# How can I remove the rows of a data frame where a certain value appears in that row in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to remove every row in my 7000 x 10 data frame where one of the row entries takes a certain value. For example, if I had 600 rows where '20' appeared in the row, how can I delete all of those?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: what did you come up with?

Comment: look into `.loc` `df.loc[df[your_col] != 20]` will remove all examples that aren't 20. If you are struggling with this I'd read the basics of pandas before moving on, but provide a sample dataframe and we will be able to help you.

Comment: In stead of 7000 x 10 data, how about you come up with 7 x 3 data, and demonstrate how the `20` appears in `6` rows, and how you would want to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

You usually are better off just making a new dataframe fulfilling the conditions you need than editing around with the old one. When in doubt you can just always assign it back to the same name, but here's a minimal example:

```py
value = 20
df_filtered = df[(df != value).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

find the relevant rows and then create new_df from the rest

```
value = 20    
rows_to_delete = df[df==value].any(axis=1)
new_df = df.loc[~rows_to_delete,:]
```